# How to find local maximum using arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I would like to find local maximum with the moving window 3x3 of a raster image but I don't know how to do this.

Could you please suggest me the way to do this?

Comment: FocalStatistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000qs000000 with a statistics type of 'maximum'. You must have a spatial analyst license for this tool.

Comment: For anyone who found this page while looking for how to delineate individual canopies, this topic links to this paper: https://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XLI-B8/563/2016/isprs-archives-XLI-B8-563-2016.pdf It gives step by step instructions on how to delineate canopies in a forested environment from rasters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157008)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Michael Miles-Stimson, the first step is to compute a new raster with the value of the minimum in your neighbourhood. This can be done using [Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000qs000000) tools.

The second step consists in finding the values of the original raster that are equal to your maximum values. This can be done using the Con tool

```
Con("raster"=="focal_stat_max", 1)
```

Note that the "non maximum" will be set to NoData in this case, but you can enter another value if you want (e.g. 0)

```
Con("raster"=="focal_stat_max", 1, 0)
```

Finally, you convert this as point using raster to point (optional)