# Extract Highest Raster Values to Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, vector

I a little bit stumped.
I have the entire world as a raster with values ranging from 0-7.
I am wanting to extract the highest values (ideally only those from 6-7) as points.
Is there any simple way i can do this?
Current i am manually putting points in the high areas that i can visually see and then using "Extract values from raster" to give the points a value.

This is tedious and also isn't 100% accurate and i also have to produce it on many rasters...

Here is an image so you can see what i mean (Just put in NZ for an example) Basically just wanting points in all the red areas (values 7-8) and then i can Extract values from Raster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [selecting the higher values](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-attributes.htm) and then just [converting to points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-point.htm)?

Comment: I dont understand your question fully. What if there is a 6.8 next to a 6.9, then you only want a point at 6.9? Then I think you want to find [local maximas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124115/how-to-find-local-maximum-using-arcgis). Or do you want points at every pixel if the value is >=6?

Comment: @user2856 how do you select only the high values in a raster?

Comment: @BERA Yes i am wanting all the points >=6.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, thanks everyone.
This is what i did
Because my Raster is float i X it by 10000 to make it whole numbers.
I then converted my Raster to an Interg
I "Build Raster Attribute Table"
I then selected the high values in my attribute table & did the Raster to Points

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a "Reclassify" for the high-value-regions. Then convert it to singlepart polygons, convert them back to raster via FID and then use the tool "Zonal Statistics", then taking the Raster Calculator with something like Con(Max=Reclass, Max) and convert the resulting raster to point?

Comment: Hey, i tried this, but my values are decimal. I cant seem to put in a range in the New Values and i cannot write out every decimal value  from 5 to 6. (i.e 5.1 = 5.1, 5.11 = 5.11 ...) Any ideas? I want to keep the high cells with their current values.  I will post a picture

Comment: I posted my picture up the top, i wasn't sure how to post it in the comment @Anna